# Select the row values of dataframe if row name is present in column name of another dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

If I have **df1**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col_Name': {0: 'A', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}, 'X': {0: 12, 1: 23, 2: 223}, 'Z': {0: 42, 1: 33, 2: 28 }})
```

and **df2**

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Col': {0: 'Y', 1: 'X', 2: 'Z'}, 'Low1': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0}, 'High1': {0: 10, 1: 10, 2: 630}, 'Low2': {0: 10, 1: 10, 2: 630}, 'High2': {0: 50, 1: 50, 2: 3000}, 'Low3': {0: 50, 1: 50, 2: 3000}, 'High3': {0: 100, 1: 100, 2: 8500}, 'Low4': {0: 100, 1: 100, 2: 8500}, 'High4': {0: 'np.inf', 1: 'np.inf', 2: 'np.inf'}})
```

Select the row values of df2 if row is present in column name of df1.

**Expected Output: df3**

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Col': {0: 'X', 1: 'Z'}, 'Low1': {0: 0, 1: 0}, 'High1': {0: 10, 1: 630}, 'Low2': {0: 10, 1: 630}, 'High2': {0: 50, 1: 3000}, 'Low3': {0: 50, 1: 3000}, 'High3': {0: 100, 1: 8500}, 'Low4': {0: 100, 1: 8500}, 'High4': {0: 'np.inf', 1: 'np.inf'}})
```

How to do it?

Comment: ``df2.loc[df2.isin(df1.columns).any(axis=1)]``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a boolean list to select the rows of `df2` that you want. This list can be created by looking at each value in the `Col` column and asking if the value is in the columns of `df1`

```py
df3 = df2[[col in df1.columns for col in df2['Col']]]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can drop the non-relevant col and use the other columns...

```
df3 = df2[df2['Col'].isin(list(df1.drop('Col_Name',axis=1).columns))]
```

[image]